# spliting dataset, but it didn't work in training dataset

Tags: python

I want finish this part, but in `train_data`, it didn't work

```
dataset , h, c = re.load_csv("Irs.csv")
ratio = round(len(dataset)/5)
for i in range(0,5):
    Test_data = dataset[ratio*i:ratio*(i+1),:]
    Train_data = dataset[0:ratio*i&ratio*(i+1):-1,:]
```

I know the problem is 100% in `&` but I can't figure out how to change.

Comment: `ratio` & `dataset` are not defined.

Comment: @ScottHunter no, this is one part of my code, besides, I can got test_data correctly, thanks

Comment: The other user was trying to tell you  that we ask that you please provide a [mcve] including sample input, sample output, and reproducible code for your current solution so that we can understand your problem better

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. What does _it didn't work_ mean, exactly? There's no description of the issue, not enough information to reproduce it or find it ourselves, nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a list of the indices required to construct `Train_data` and then use `.loc` to access those rows, like so:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    Test_data = dataset.loc[ratio*i:ratio*(i+1),:]
    indices = list(range(0, ratio*i)) + list(range(ratio*(i+1), len(dataset)))
    Train_data = dataset.loc[indices,:]
```